# Python MultiIndex Column Rename

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I am a **NEWBIE** to panda framework. I tried various things shown below and I Want to rename a column name in pandas dataframe , can some one please guide me with this. The column is multilevel pivot column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\cod_sheets\18_09_18.xlsx')


df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["REGION NAME","Month"],values=["CNNO","AMOUNT COLLECTED"],
columns=["CDS_STATUS",] ,aggfunc={"CNNO":'count',"AMOUNT COLLECTED":'sum'}, margins=True)
df_pivot.rename(columns = {"CDS_STATUS":"CDS"})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJEkS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJEkS.png)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the argument to `df_pivot.rename(columns = {"CDS_STATUS":"CDS"})` that  is `df_pivot.rename(columns = {"CDS_STATUS":"CDS"},inplace=True)`

Comment: Actually I have tried it is not working because CDS STATUS column is comes under other column (AMOUNT COLLECTED) and it is the parent column. What you told works for the parent column but not the child column